# Multiple images upload issue using https on .NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, https, iis-10

I have this problem:
I am trying to figure out why all my requests for image uploading are pending for more than minute when I try to upload more than 1 image. I relatively fast find out that problem is https. When I visit my web site without http then everything is working fine. I want to point out that problem is not in code meaning that problem is not that request comes in my ASP.NET Web Api controller then there is some database or file system delay.No, problem is that there is huge delay, almost two minutes then when request comes to controller it executes in 2 or 3 seconds.
[image]

Server configuration: IIS 10

EDIT:
Here is update and bounty also.
I figured out something. When on IIS I go to site settings and go to SSL settings and check Client cerficates to "Accept" it seems that upload is working. But problem is that users are promted to install some certificate before visisting website. Obvoiusly it is something with SSL but it is hard to figure out what.

Comment: It might have to do with this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/295070/ssl-https-connection-slow-with-one-certificate-but-faster-with-others

Comment: Client cerficates to "Accept" it seems that upload is working. I dont understand this. by choosing the accept option. you ask the client for certificate but even if he doesnt have it you serve him the content. so by this logic, your upload must happen without this as well